# How to get sequencial numbers from an array in php

Tags: php, loops, sequence

I am having an array say
`arr[]={1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18}`
and I need 3 blocks containing 3 elements each.[3 will be dynamic]
The output should be

```
block[1]={1,2,3}
block[2]={6,7,8}
block[3]={10,11,12}
```

what would be the looping script in php

Comment: show your code what you do so far.

Comment: hint: `array_chunk`

Comment: `array_chunk(array_slice($array, 0, 9, true), 3, true);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$arr = range(1, 18);
$result = array_chunk($arr, 3);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Using this code I am getting this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )
 ). But in 2nd block it should be {6,7,8} cause {4,6,7} is not sequential

Answer (score 1):

Use **[array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)**

```
$arr=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18];
unset($arr[3]); // unset key 4
$chunks = array_chunk($arr, 3,true);// pass true here
print_r($chunks);
```

Comment: Using this code I am getting this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )
 ). But in 2nd block it should be {6,7,8} cause {4,6,7} is not sequential.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18];
$block = array_chunk($arr,3);
print_r($block);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 18
        )

)
```

---

```
$block[] = array_slice($arr, 0, 3, true);
$block[] = array_slice($arr, 4, 3, true);
$block[] = array_slice($arr, 7, 3, true);
print_r($block);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 7
            [6] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [7] => 10
            [8] => 11
            [9] => 12
        )

)
```

> Refer :  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/8E0Jp)

Comment: Using this code I am getting this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 14
        )
 ). But in 2nd block it should be {6,7,8} cause {4,6,7} is not sequential

Comment: 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18 . This sequence will be chunked into 1,2,3-4,6,7- 8,10,11-12,13,14-16,17,18

Comment: Could you provide your preferred output completely

Comment: (4-6-7) is not sequential. The second block would be (6-7-8)

Comment: The output would be 
block[1]={1,2,3}
block[2]={6,7,8}
block[3]={10,11,12}

Comment: $block[] = array_slice($arr, 0, 3, true);
$block[] = array_slice($arr, 4, 3, true);
$block[] = array_slice($arr, 7, 3, true);

Comment: Above code will give you what you are looking for. But we need to know the logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115070/discussion-between-zakhefron-and-user2439124).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using just one line of code.

```
$array = array_chunk(array_slice($array, 0, 9), 3);
```

`array_slice` is used to slice a part of 9 key-value pairs off of your original array.

`array_chunk` then devides it into chunks of 3 each.

#### Incorrect order?

If your array order is somehow incorrect the above code will not work. To fix this issue you will first need to `sort` your array. This can be done as follows:

```
$array = sort($array);
```

The above function will sort your array nemerically from low to high.

Doing a test run returns me:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
    [2]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(7)
    [1]=>
    int(8)
    [2]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
```

#### Resources

- [array_chunk - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
- [array_slice() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: Using this code I am getting this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 10 [2] => 11 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 ) ). But in 2nd block it should be {6,7,8} cause {4,6,7} is not sequential

Comment: You tell me your array consists of a range from 1, 2, 3 etc. The only way that my code won't work is if they are not actually in this order. You can use a `sort` on your array before using my code to fix this.